# How do I unit test a custom ant task?

Tags: ant, junit

I am writing a custom ant task that extends Task. I am using the log() method in the task. What I want to do is use a unit test while deveoping the task, but I don't know how to set up a context for the task to run in to initialise the task as if it were running in ant.

This is the custom Task:

```
public class CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles extends Task {
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        log("CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles begin execute()");

        log("CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles end execute()");
    }
}
```

This is the unit test code:

```
CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles task = new CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles();
task.execute();
```

When the code is run as a test it gives a NullPointerException when it calls log.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.log(Task.java:346)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.log(Task.java:334)
    at uk.co.tbp.ant.custom.CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles.execute(CopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles.java:40)
    at uk.co.tbp.ant.custom.test.TestCopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles.testCopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles(TestCopyAndSetPropertiesForFiles.java:22)
```

Does anybody know a way to provide a context or stubs or something similar to the task?

Thanks,

Rob.

Accepted answer from Abarax. I was able to call task.setProject(new Project());
The code now executes OK (except no logging appears in th console - at least I can exercise the code :-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Ant source code these are the two relevent classes: [ProjectComponent](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/ProjectComponent.java.html) and [Task](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/Task.java.html)

You are calling the log method from Task:

```
public void log(String msg) {
     log(msg, Project.MSG_INFO);
}
```

Which calls:

```
public void log(String msg, int msgLevel) {
  if (getProject() != null) {
    getProject().log(this, msg, msgLevel);
  } else {
    super.log(msg, msgLevel);
  }
}
```

Since you do not have project set it will call "super.log(msg, msgLevel)"

```
public void log(String msg, int msgLevel) {
  if (getProject() != null) {
     getProject().log(msg, msgLevel);
  } else {
    // 'reasonable' default, if the component is used without
    // a Project ( for example as a standalone Bean ).
    // Most ant components can be used this way.
    if (msgLevel <= Project.MSG_INFO) {
      System.err.println(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like this may be your problem.  Your task needs a project context.

Answer (score 8):

Or better yet, decouple the task object itself from the logic (lets call it TaskImpl) inside the task - so that you can pass in your own dependencies (e.g., the logger). Then, instead of testing the task object, you test TaskImpl -> which you can pass in the logger, and any other weird bits and pieces it might need to do its job. Then unit testing is a matter of mocking the dependencies.

Comment: Definitely do this! TDD is a design methodology, when Ant provides the design, you can't do much - especially if you inherit from a framework provided superclass not under your control. You want to test *only* the functionality you provide, *not* Ants implementation of Task. Voting up!

Answer (score 1):

Ant has a handy class called BuildFileTest that extends the JUnit TestCase class.  You can use it to test the behaviour of individual targets in a build file.  Using this would take care of all the annoying context.

There's a [Test The Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html#TestingTasks) chapter in the Apache Ant Writing Tasks Tutorial that describes this.